# Custom Lint check not running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I am currently trying to write a  custom lint check that I am working on. I have created a separate java project and included it as a jar.

My problem is that no matter what, it seems that my custom check is not being run when analyzing my code base.

I've included a registry

```
class MyIssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {
override val issues: List<Issue>
    get() = listOf(MyIssues.ISSUE_PATTERN)
}
```

And a detector

```
class MyIssueDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {

    override fun getApplicableUastTypes() = listOf(UClass::class.java)

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext) =
        MyIssueDetector(context)

    class MyIssueDetector(private val context: JavaContext) : UElementHandler() {
        override fun visitClass(node: UClass) {
            context.report(MyIssues.ISSUE_PATTERN, context.getNameLocation(node), "This is just a test")
        }
    }
}
```

I've also added `attributes("Lint-Registry-v2": "com.pathto.lint.MyIssueRegistry")` to my java project's gradle and included it in my app gradle as `lintChecks project(":lint")`

AFAIK this topic- My code should be throwing a warning everytime it reads a class, but the lint check is not being ran. Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: Could you please attach a source of `MyIssues.ISSUE_PATTERN`?

Answer (score 0):

first, check your lint.jar is placed on the right path. my path is ~/.android/lint/lint.jar. 
 
then execute command '$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/lint --show | grep 'your issue name'' to check your custom lint is attached or not.  
 
and then you can put some log to your custom lint implementation just like using "System.out.println()" 
hope this can help u.